# Combobox Itemsource Binding does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to fill my Combobox ItemsSource using Binding in Xaml with a collection of data `ObservableCollection` but I always get the Combobox ItemsSource null .

**WPF UserControl Cs Code :** ( Update the code )

```
    public ObservableCollection<User> users { get; set; }


      public partial class MainWindow : Window

         
         {
            InitializeComponent();
            User user1 = new User("Mariah", 15);
            User user2 = new User("John", 19 );
            users = new ObservableCollections<User>();
            users.Add(user1);
            users.Add(user2);
            this.DataContext = this;          
            Console.WriteLine(ComboBoxUsers.Items.Count); // always 0
            Console.WriteLine(ComboBoxUsers.ItemsSource); // always null
         }
```

**WPF UserControl Xaml Code :** ( Updated my code )

```
          <ComboBox SelectedIndex = "0" x:Name="ComboBoxUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding users, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="11" Grid.Row="3" Height="30"  Margin="10,5,5,5">
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
             <Image  IsEnabled="False" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
             <TextBlock x:Name="textblock" IsEnabled="False"   Text="{Binding Name} />

        </StackPanel>
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="IsEnable" Value="{Binding IsEnable}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>

            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}">
                    <Setter
                Property="Visibility"
                Value="{Binding IsHidden}" />
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        </ComboBox>
```

**Class User**

```
 public class User 
    {
       public string Name  { get; set; }
       public int Age { get; set; }
       public User(string name, int age)
           {
              this.Name = name;
              this.Age = age;
           }
    }
```

What is the source of this problem?

[image: SelectedIndex always take -1]

Comment: I have added them , sorry my code was not completed , I have updated my question

Comment: I have already set the `ItemsSource` of the combobox to Users

Comment: Yes I have added this portion of code `ComboBoxUsers.ItemsSource = users;` for test , maybe my question was not very cleared , the binding in the code behind ( C# code ) worked well but the problem appears only in the xaml code

Comment: Also note that `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the ItemsSource Binding has no effect and should be removed, even if the Binding would work.

Comment: Alright , but I would like to solve my problem first , see the update please

Comment: This is already exists but I still get this problem of binding , my combobox still have itemsource null

Comment: See the update please , ( just I didn't wrote the complete code )

Comment: Please see again the update

Comment: There is no any binding error messages in the output of my window

Comment: I have updated my question see the Cs code please to understand the problem that I got.

Comment: You need to pay attention to what you wrote. Even as you miss `ComboBoxUsers.ItemsSource = Users;` assignment in example. Or `User user1 = User` - where you lost `new`?

Comment: Sorry , I was in a hurry when writing the code

Answer (score -2):

Discarding unnecessary (which is not relevant to the question or has syntax errors), your example with a little formatting works fine.

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxUsers"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" 
          FontFamily="Arial"
          FontSize="11"
          Grid.Row="3" 
          Height="30" 
          Margin="10,5,5,5">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <TextBlock IsEnabled="False" 
                           Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int Age { get; }

    public User(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Initialize collection with some items
        Users = new ObservableCollection<User>
        {
            new User("Mariah", 15),
            new User("John", 19)
        };

        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Remarks:**

Your

> ```
> Console.WriteLine(ComboBoxUsers.Items.Count); // always 0
> Console.WriteLine(ComboBoxUsers.ItemsSource); // always null
> ```

because you use **Binding**. You needn't access `ItemsSource` or `Items.Count` through `ComboBox` - you should use **binded** collection `Users` (e.g. `Users.Count`) to manipulate or get ComboBox content.

### EDIT.

About `SelectedItem`. You should define for yourself, you want use **Bindings** or work with ComboBox **directly**.

**Binding** push you to NOT use `ComboBox.SelectedItem/Index/Value` whatever. Even not access `ComboBoxUsers` to get some data. **Binding** is closely related to, for example, the [MVVM Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm). If you decided to use Bindings - forget about accessing directly to `ComboBox` or it data properties `SelectedItem/Index/Value` or similar.

If you use Bindings - you should create a property (e.g. `SelectedUser`) for SelectedItem (same as you create property `Users` for your ItemsSource ) and bind to it:

**XAML** *(introducing binding for `SelectedItem` property and `SelectionChanged` handler)*:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxUsers"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}"
          SelectionChanged="OnUserSelectionChanged"
          FontFamily="Arial"
          FontSize="11"
          Grid.Row="3" 
          Height="30" 
          Margin="10,5,5,5">
</ComboBox>
```

**Code-behind** *(introducing property `SelectedUser` and `OnUserSelectionChanged` handler)*:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; }
    // Here would be stored your Binded selected item
    public User SelectedUser { get; set; }

    // And here is your handler when selection changed
    private void OnUserSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // SelectedUser property stores selected in ComboBox item,
        // so you can use it directly
        _ = MessageBox.Show(SelectedUser.Name);

        // Even if you wish to get directly - it is possible 
        // (thanks to @Clemens):
        var selectedUser = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as User;
        var selectediIndex = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedIndex;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Users = new ObservableCollection<User>
        {
            new User("Mariah", 15),
            new User("John", 19)           
        };

        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Repeat same algorithm for each property you wish to Bind (e.g. `SelectedIndex`):

```
SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedUserIndex}"
public int SelectedUserIndex { get; set; }
```

**Result:**

[image]

Decide for yourself, what you need. Nice modern **Bindings** or old boring `(sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem`.

Comment: I didn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface to simplify example.

Comment: First of all ,I'm still getting the combobox with null values .. you solution won't works for me. Secondly , you missed the image control in the StackPanel , so maybe this change a little bit in the code and the result.

Comment: If this worked as you tell me , so try to add ` ComboBoxUsers.SelectedItem` and you see that the item is null ( The `SelectedIndex` is set to 0 in the Xaml code )

Comment: What you have said is wrong , because the `Combobox` still null in the code and I can't access to `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex`

Comment: @abdou31 Try to concentrate on what you were asking in the question. The Image element is irrelevant for displaying instances of the User class as you have shown it. Saying the "ComboBox is null" makes no sense at all. Remember you were accessing it from your MainWindow constructor when you set the ItemsSource in code. The example shown in this answer just works. Probably just take it and start from there. If you have problems with binding SelectedItem or SelectedIndex, ask another question.

Comment: @abdou31 And please do not tell people that help you "*What you have said is wrong*" when you have no idea what you are doing, and your code is a mess.

Comment: @Clemens , I said this after clarifying my object and what I want to achieve

Comment: @abdou31 If your question is still why ComboBoxUsers.ItemsSource is null in the constructor, that is because Bindings are evaluated later, after the constructor is finished, as already said.

Comment: Yes I got this answer , my question is why I can't get the selectedItem ??? why the SelectedItem and SelectedIndex are always null ?? how can I get them???

Comment: @abdou31, check EDIT part of answer. Try understand, that Binding isn't **auto-assign** of some property (e.g. `{Binding Users}` not same as `ComboBox.ItemsSource = Users`). It is **Binding**.

Comment: What you have added won't works for me !! ( modern binding )

Comment: What about setting `SelectedIndex` ??? What's the value of the `SelectedIndex` ?? `SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedUserIndex}"
public int SelectedUserIndex { get; set; }` , your solution seems to be reviewed

Comment: It is copypastable example, you can create test WPF app, copypaste code from answer and get things up. It MAY NOT work on your original app, because I don't know what you have there and how you implementing. I attach screenshots not from Photoshop, but to demonstrate how it works and that this works. About `SelectedIndex` - I read your comment after edit and update answer with providing example for SelectedIndex binding.

Comment: I will create a new application and I will give you a proof that your example won't works

Comment: Tested your solution didn't give me what I need , what I need exactly is getting the combobox with selectedIndex 0 , that's what I said from the first and get the selectedItem by default in the code behind

Comment: You do not need a SelectionChanged handler when you bind the SelectedItem/-Value/-Index property of a ComboBox (or any other Selector). React on changes in the setter of the source property of the Binding.

Comment: As @Clemens noticed, you can access `SelectedIndex`/`SelectedValue`/`SelectedItem` out of constructor (e.g. in `OnUserSelectionChanged` handler from example). What's the problem you have while trying to get SelectedIndex by Binding or by `(sender as ComboBox).SelectedIndex`?

Comment: I have another combobox related to this combobox so I need to get the default selected as first item to get the second combobox filled ( depond on the first ) for that reason I need to get the first item in the first combobox as selected .

Comment: Try do what you want NOT is constructor. Create for example Window.Loaded handler and put there your `ComboBoxUsers.SelectedIndex`.

Comment: The problem is that I still always get `ComboBoxUsers.SelectedIndex` as -1 , I think it's a bug in .Net Framework

Comment: Please try to understand me , I would like to get the first selected item not set the selected item

Comment: @abdou31, by default there isn't any selected item until you select it or set from code. So it returns -1. You want to have default selected item when window loads? Set it in Window.Loaded handler e.g. `ComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;` - then first item from collection would be selected when window will be shown.